Implicit differentiation choice
I was reading Calculus early transcendentals by Howard Anton, in which I encountered an example as follows,
Find the slope of tangents of a sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ in the direction of $y$ at points $(2/3,1/3,2/3)$ and $(2/3,1/3,-2/3)$.
They assumed that $z$ is defined implicitly as a function of $x$ and $y$ and found,
$$\frac{dz}{dy}=-\frac{y}{z}$$ and slopes are $1/2$ and $-1/2$ respectively.
My question is, why do we assume $z$ is defined implicitly? Now for instance, If I assume that $x$ is defined implicitly, then I will get
$$\frac{dx}{dy}=-\frac{y}{x}$$ but the slope will be $1/2$ at both the points and still tangent is in the direction of $y$.
I can imagine both the plots and their tangents, just a bit confused about which one to choose.

The exercise is somewhat ambiguous on this point.

@callculus42 I'm not sure what you are trying to say.

That is not clear what they want: dz/dy or dx/dy.

Why does it matter?

In 3D with $(x,y,z)$ coordinates, we think of $z$ as the vertical direction, so "slope" is the rate of change of $z$ with respect to some change in the $xy$-plane. This is analogous to how in 2D "slope" means $\frac{dy}{dx}$ and not $\frac{dx}{dy}$.

Quiet convincing! Thanks!!

As claimed in OP we are after the slope of the graph of $z(x,y)$ (given implicitly) at two points. These functions are different as $z(x,y)=\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}$ near $(2/3,1/3,2/3)$ and $z(x,y)=-\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}$ near $(2/3,1/3,-2/3).$  We want to find the slopes of the tangent lines with respect to $y$. Therefore we intersect the graphs with the plane $x=2/3.$ Two solutions follow.
Solution $1$
Consider $z(x,y)$  and $z_0=z(x_0,y_0).$ We are looking for the slope of $y\mapsto z(x_0,y)$ at the point $(x_0,y_0).$ The slope is equal $\displaystyle{\partial z\over \partial y}(x_0,y_0).$ Applying $\displaystyle {\partial \over \partial y}$ to the equation $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ gives
$$2y+2z{\partial z\over \partial y}=0$$ Thus
$${\partial z\over \partial y}(x_0,y_0)=-{y_0\over z_0}$$ provided that $z_0\neq 0.$ Substituting $(2/3,1/3,2/3) $ gives
$${\partial z\over \partial y}(2/3,1/3)=-{1/3\over 2/3}=-{1\over 2}$$ Similarly for $(2/3,1/3,-2/3)$ we get $${\partial z\over \partial y}(2/3,1/3)={1\over 2}$$
Solution $2$
Let a function $z(x,y)$ be given implicitly as $f(x,y,z)=0.$ For a point $P_0:=(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ such that $f(x_0,y_0,z_0)=0 ,$ the tangent plane at the point $P_0$ is given by
$$\nabla f(x_0,y_0,z_0)\circ (x-x_0,y-y_0,z-z_0)=0 $$ provided that $\nabla f(x_0,y_0,z_0)\neq 0.$ The tangent line in the direction of $y$ is given by $x=x_0$ and $\nabla f(x_0,y_0,z_0)\circ (x-x_0,y-y_0,z-z_0)=0,$ i.e. by
$$x=x_0,\quad \nabla f(x_0,y_0,z_0)\circ (0,y-y_0,z-z_0)=0$$ Thus the slope at the point $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ is equal to $-{\partial f\over \partial y}/ {\partial f\over \partial z}.$  In our case $f(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z^2$ and $(x_0,y_0,z_0)=(2/3,1/3,\pm 2/3).$  Moreover $${1\over 2}\nabla f(2/3,1/3,\pm 2/3)= (2/3,1/3,\pm 2/3)$$ Hence the slopes are equal $\mp 1/2.$

Thank you for your detailed answer, but it does not answer my question.

I have added an explanation at the begining of the answer.
